# How to refactor simple dataframe parsing code with Pandas

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, dataframe, refactoring

I am using Pandas to parse a dataframe that I have created:

```
# Initial DF    
A    B    C
0  -1  qqq  XXX
1  20  www  CCC
2  30  eee  VVV
3  -1  rrr  BBB
4  50  ttt  NNN
5  60  yyy  MMM
6  70  uuu  LLL
7  -1  iii  KKK
8  -1  ooo  JJJ
```

My goal is to analyze column A and apply the following conditions to the dataframe:

1. Investigate every row
2. determine if `df['A'].iloc[index]=-1`
3. if true and `index=0` mark first row as to be removed
4. if true and `index=N` mark last row as to be removed
5. if `0<index<N` and `df['A'].iloc[index]=-1` and the previous or following row contain -1 (`df['A'].iloc[index+]=-1` or
   `df['A'].iloc[index-1]=-1`), mark row as to be removed; else replace
   -1 with the average of the previous and following value

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
# Final DF    
A    B    C
0  20  www  CCC
1  30  eee  VVV
2  40  rrr  BBB
3  50  ttt  NNN
4  60  yyy  MMM
5  70  uuu  LLL
```

I was able to achieve my goal by writing a simple code that applies the conditions mentioned above:

import pandas as pd

```
# create dataframe
data = {'A':[-1,20,30,-1,50,60,70,-1,-1],
        'B':['qqq','www','eee','rrr','ttt','yyy','uuu','iii','ooo'],
        'C':['XXX','CCC','VVV','BBB','NNN','MMM','LLL','KKK','JJJ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# If df['A'].iloc[index]==-1:
#   - option 1: remove row if first or last row are equal to -1
#   - option 2: remove row if previous or following row contains -1 (df['A'].iloc[index-1]==-1 or df['A'].iloc[index+1]==-1)
#   - option 3: replace df['A'].iloc[index] if: df['A'].iloc[index]==-1 and (df['A'].iloc[index-1]==-1 or df['A'].iloc[index+1]==-1)
N = len(df.index) # number of rows
index_vect = []   # store indexes of rows to be deleated
for index in range(0,N):

    # option 1
    if index==0 and df['A'].iloc[index]==-1:
        index_vect.append(index)
    elif index>1 and index<N and df['A'].iloc[index]==-1:

       # option 2
        if df['A'].iloc[index-1]==-1 or df['A'].iloc[index+1]==-1:
            index_vect.append(index)

        # option 3
        else:
            df['A'].iloc[index] = int((df['A'].iloc[index+1]+df['A'].iloc[index-1])/2)

    # option 1        
    elif index==N and df['A'].iloc[index]==-1:
        index_vect.append(index)

# remove rows to be deleated
df = df.drop(index_vect).reset_index(drop = True)
```

As you can see the code is pretty long and I would like to know if you can suggest a smarter and more efficient way to obtain the same result.
Furthermore I noticed my code return a warning message cause by the line `df['A'].iloc[index] = int((df['A'].iloc[index+1]+df['A'].iloc[index-1])/2)`
Do you know how I could optimize such line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
import numpy as np

# Let's replace -1 by Not a Number (NaN)
df.ix[df.A==-1,'A'] = np.nan

# If df.A is NaN and either the previous or next is also NaN, we don't select it
# This takes care of the condition on the first and last row too
df = df[~(df.A.isnull() & (df.A.shift(1).isnull() | df.A.shift(-1).isnull()))]

# Use interpolate to fill with the average of previous and next
df.A = df.A.interpolate(method='linear', limit=1)
```

Here's the resulting `df`:

```
    A       B       C
1   20.0    www     CCC
2   30.0    eee     VVV
3   40.0    rrr     BBB
4   50.0    ttt     NNN
5   60.0    yyy     MMM
6   70.0    uuu     LLL
```

You can then reset the index if you want to.